# Showing that the difference of two functions is affin

Tags: derivatives

Given that for two functions $f$ and $g$ it holds that $f'' = g''$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, how can it be shown that the difference of $f$ and $g$ is afin, i.e. that $f - g = ax+b$, for some a and some b.

I do **not** expect solutions, hints are enough for starting, I will try it then myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well you know that $f^{\prime\prime}(x)-g^{\prime\prime}(x) = 0$ for all $x$. What functions have  derivative equal to zero everywhere? What does this tell you about $f^\prime(x)-g^\prime(x)$?

Comment: ah of course their slope must be constant

Comment: Ok, then I can define h:= f-g, and the second derivative of h is zero, hence h must be a linear function, right?

Comment: Well that's what you want to prove, so be careful about circular reasoning. Do you know about integrals and the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: yes, I do. Could I then define h'' := f''-g'', and then int(h'') = h' = a, and thus int(h') = ax+b, for constants a,b ?

Comment: That's the idea, but just be careful using the FTC since it deals with definite integrals. But I think you can get away with just using antiderivatives.